# How to check if child element for each group is existing in object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

This is how my datastructure looks like. I need to veryfiy if every `group`-element (if it is existing at all) has a child element.

So this example would be a valid dataset. It should be invalid, if the last object would be missing. Groups can also be nested.

```
var elements = [
    {
        "_id" : "NpxZFT4TwfDvwbtKX",
        "content" : "Group 1",
        "parent" : "bmphCpyHZLhTc74Zp",
        "type" : "group"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "zQS6pXicvXk7K2rZ4",
        "content" : "Element 1",
        "parent" : "bmphCpyHZLhTc74Zp",
        "type" : "item"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "2ct9a7xE7HTrszua7",
        "content" : "Subgroup in Group 1",
        "parent" : "NpxZFT4TwfDvwbtKX",
        "type" : "group"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "HTrszua72ct9a7xE7",
        "content" : "Element 1 in Subgroup",
        "parent" : "2ct9a7xE7HTrszua7",
        "type" : "item"
    }
]
```

So I tried something like this:

```
elements.every(
    element => elements.some(elm => elm.parent === elm._id)
)
```

Comment: Right now. your structure is invalid because you are missing commas, between the objects. Also, you mention `group` and `document`, but neither  of those things appear in your sample.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I've corrected the post. By document I mean one object (because it is data of a mongoDB)

Comment: You can't use the same argument name in the `some` call as you do in the `every` call. Which `element` is which? So change one of them so something else.

Comment: Sure, just filter the outer `elements` for ones that are `group`s. Something like `elements.filter(el => el.type === 'group').every(...)` You could also filter the inner `elements` too to make sure a group doesn't reference another group, with something like `element.filter(el => el.type !== 'group').some(...)`.

Comment: This kind of thing would be much easier if you used an object whose keys are the IDs, rather than an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array#reduce` to create a map of groups with/without children. Iterate the map with `Array#every` to determine if all groups have children:

```js
const allGroupsWithChildren = [{"_id":"NpxZFT4TwfDvwbtKX","content":"Group 1","parent":"bmphCpyHZLhTc74Zp","type":"group"},{"_id":"zQS6pXicvXk7K2rZ4","content":"Element 1","parent":"bmphCpyHZLhTc74Zp","type":"item"},{"_id":"2ct9a7xE7HTrszua7","content":"Subgroup in Group 1","parent":"NpxZFT4TwfDvwbtKX","type":"group"},{"_id":"HTrszua72ct9a7xE7","content":"Element 1 in Subgroup","parent":"2ct9a7xE7HTrszua7","type":"item"}];

const hasGroupsWithNoChildren = [{"_id":"NpxZFT4TwfDvwbtKX","content":"Group 1","parent":"bmphCpyHZLhTc74Zp","type":"group"},{"_id":"zQS6pXicvXk7K2rZ4","content":"Element 1","parent":"bmphCpyHZLhTc74Zp","type":"item"},{"_id":"2ct9a7xE7HTrszua7","content":"Subgroup in Group 1","parent":"NpxZFT4TwfDvwbtKX","type":"group"}];

const isAllWithChildren = (elements) => {
    const map = elements.reduce((map, o) => { // create map of groups
      if(o.type === 'group' && !map.has(o._id)) {
         map.set(o._id, false); // if a group doesn't exist, it  starts as childless - false
      }
      
      map.set(o.parent, true); // a child changes it's parent group has children status to true

      return map;
    }, new Map());
    
    return [...map.values()].every((value) => value); // if all map values are true, every group has at least one child
}

console.log(isAllWithChildren(allGroupsWithChildren));
console.log(isAllWithChildren(hasGroupsWithNoChildren));
```